# Automator :: Remove 6 digit date from filename; append current date

Tags: finder, command-line, automator, script, automation

I apologize in advance if this has been answered but have performed a lengthy search in hope of a solution.

I have a working Automator app that appends the current six-digit date (YYMMDD) to the end of the file name:

- Input: Filename.txt
- Output: Filename_181212.txt

Current bash command:

```
today=$(date +%y%m%d)
for f in "$@"
do
    basename=${f##*/}
    filename=${basename%.*}
    path=${f%/*}
    ext=${f##*.}
    newfilename="$filename"_"$today"
    mv "$f" "$path"/"$newfilename"."$ext"
done
```

This is great but after using it regularly, I have realized it would be nice not only append the current date but first check to see if a date is already appended to the filename; if so, remove it and append the current date, otherwise simply append the current date.

There two scenarios:

1. Filename contains any date (previous/current/future) in the 6-digit format described previously preceded by an underscore (Filename_181212.txt)
2. Filename does not contain at 6-digit date format appended to it (Filename.txt)

I realize that the solution I am hoping for will remove any six digits and its preceding "_" if it exists, whether it is a date or not.

Is it possible to precede my current bash command with something like:

> if any combination of numbers exist immediately before the file
>   extension (".ext") AND contains exactly 6 digits AND is preceded by
>   an underscore ("_")
>
> then remove the underscore plus 6 digits AND run the bash command
>   listed above
>
> if not then run the bash command above

Summary
I'm trying to alleviate manually removing dates that may exist on a file name before appending the current date to them. Some files may have dates and others may not.

Comment: Yes but it seems like in this case, the date command is irrelevant because only 6 digits (plus preceding underscore) need to be found regardless if it is a past, previous or future date.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment realizing it is stupid.

Comment: The date in file name is not Date, just plain text (numbers) but we see it as date. So if you delete all numbers in file name will that work ?

Comment: I believe so but the "_" will also need to be removed because one will be added when the current date is appended. As a reminder, if the date doesn't exist, then nothing is removed; it simply gets passed to the command that appends the date (which I currently have).

Comment: that is quite surgical process you are asking for.  And just deleting file name and replacing if with date is not an option for you.

Comment: Okay. I guess I was being optimistic and thinking that there could be a conditional statement that says something like: if  x exists, then do y + z; if not just do z... where x is something like "_181212," y is to remove x and z is to append current date.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: No, I am not saying it is not possible, it is just that I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do as you requested:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%y%m%d)

for f in "$@"; do

    filebasename=${f##*/}
    filename=${filebasename%.*}
    path=${f%/*}
    ext=${f##*.}

    if [[ "$filename" =~ ^.*_[0-9]{6}$ ]]; then

        filename="$(sed -E -e 's/_[0-9]{6}$//'<<<"$filename")"

        newfilename="$filename"_"$today"
        mv "$f" "$path"/"$newfilename"."$ext"   

    else    

        newfilename="$filename"_"$today"
        mv "$f" "$path"/"$newfilename"."$ext"

    fi

done
```

---

Note that when used within a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow*, you may need to add the full *path* to `sed` in the *code* provided, e.g.: `/usr/bin/sed`

Comment: Okay. For clarity, if I change the variable of 'basename' (and its reference in the 'filename' variable) to something such as 'filebasename' then there should not be a conflict if used directly in the terminal or command line?

Comment: @Jeremy W, Yes, changing it to anything other then an existing command name is a good thing to do, 'filebasename' is fine or anything other then exactly "baesname" in this use case. I left it as you originally wrote it so you'd be able to more easily see what code I added to your existing code. I'll update it in my answer now the I know you are aware of it.  Also, see the updated note.